# Предлагаю объединить метки “существительные" и “существительное”

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Предлагаю объединить метки “существительные" и “существительное”. Мне кажется, мы отдаем предпочтение множественному числу. Тогда пусть метка “существительные” будет главной, а “существительное” – синонимом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метки объединены, синонимы созданы.

Спасибо за помощь!